# Can't find element with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm still learn to code with python. I really need help to scrape the element from this website:

https://www.tokopedia.com/craftdale/crossback-apron-hijau-army?src=topads

I want to get Review data (Review Time) from Review ***(Ulasan)*** container

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcchw.png)

This is HTML from the site

```
<p disabled="" data-testid="txtDateGivenReviewFilter0" class="css-oals0c-unf-heading e1qvo2ff8">1 bulan lalu</p>
```

I've tried to get the element with this code

```
review = soup.findAll('p',class_='css-oals0c-unf-heading e1qvo2ff8')
```

or

```
review= soup.findAll('p',id_='txtDateGivenReviewFilter0')
```

But the result i only get empty data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et2iT.png)

Can anybody fix this problem? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When you analyse the website, the website makes ajax calls to retrieve different information in the website. To get the review information, it makes an ajax call to a specific endpoint with json payload.

```
import requests, json

payload = [{"operationName": "PDPReviewRatingQuery", "variables": {"productId": 353506414}, "query": "query PDPReviewRatingQuery($productId: Int!) {\n  ProductRatingQuery(productId: $productId) {\n    ratingScore\n    totalRating\n    totalRatingWithImage\n    detail {\n      rate\n      totalReviews\n      percentage\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}, {"operationName": "PDPReviewImagesQuery", "variables": {"productID": 353506414, "page": 1}, "query": "query PDPReviewImagesQuery($page: Int, $productID: Int!) {\n  ProductReviewImageListQuery(page: $page, productID: $productID) {\n    detail {\n      reviews {\n        reviewer {\n          fullName\n          profilePicture\n          __typename\n        }\n        reviewId\n        message\n        rating\n        updateTime\n        isReportable\n        __typename\n      }\n      images {\n        imageAttachmentID\n        description\n        uriThumbnail\n        uriLarge\n        reviewID\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}, {"operationName": "PDPReviewHelpfulQuery", "variables": {"productID": 353506414}, "query": "query PDPReviewHelpfulQuery($productID: Int!) {\n  ProductMostHelpfulReviewQuery(productId: $productID) {\n    shop {\n      shopId\n      __typename\n    }\n    list {\n      reviewId\n      message\n      productRating\n      reviewCreateTime\n      reviewCreateTimestamp\n      isReportable\n      isAnonymous\n      imageAttachments {\n        attachmentId\n        imageUrl\n        imageThumbnailUrl\n        __typename\n      }\n      user {\n        fullName\n        image\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      likeDislike {\n        totalLike\n        likeStatus\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}, {"operationName": "PDPReviewListQuery", "variables": {"page": 1, "rating": 0, "withAttachment": 0, "productID": 353506414, "perPage": 10}, "query": "query PDPReviewListQuery($productID: Int!, $page: Int!, $perPage: Int!, $rating: Int!, $withAttachment: Int!) {\n  ProductReviewListQuery(productId: $productID, page: $page, perPage: $perPage, rating: $rating, withAttachment: $withAttachment) {\n    shop {\n      shopId\n      name\n      image\n      url\n      __typename\n    }\n    list {\n      reviewId\n      message\n      productRating\n      reviewCreateTime\n      reviewCreateTimestamp\n      isReportable\n      isAnonymous\n      imageAttachments {\n        attachmentId\n        imageUrl\n        imageThumbnailUrl\n        __typename\n      }\n      reviewResponse {\n        message\n        createTime\n        __typename\n      }\n      likeDislike {\n        totalLike\n        likeStatus\n        __typename\n      }\n      user {\n        userId\n        fullName\n        image\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}]

res = requests.post("https://gql.tokopedia.com/", json=payload)

data = res.json()

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The above script will save the review information as a json to a file.

In order to get the rating score

```
print(data[0]['data']['ProductRatingQuery']['ratingScore'])
``
```

Comment: so i must get the json data first, and then parsing the data?

Comment: Yes, you run the script , you get the json data and then parse the json. The json has all review data you asked for

Comment: is it still possible to get the data from find method with beautiful soup? or the only one method to get data is from json request?

Comment: You can't get the data from beautifulsoup because the data is not loaded as soon as the site opens. It makes an ajax call, retrieves the data and then loads it up. So, you can't scrape via beautifulsoup. And moreover this json has all review data. Parsing json should be easy

Comment: hello, can you help me to parse the data that i want in that json data? it's full of many data, i just want to get "Time Review" data

Comment: i use this code `import json


with open('cobauhuy.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()


obj = json.loads(data)

items = []
for item in obj:
    items.append(item['ratingScore'])
    
    
print(items)`

Comment: Got it. i can get the rating score correctly. but how to make loop function from it? i want to get all the rating score @bigbounty

Comment: `for review in data[3]['data']:
                                                                            
                print(review['ProductReviewListQuery']['list'][1]['reviewCreateTime'])`                
                                                                                                                                 
                                                                  can i make the loop function like that?

Comment: Hi @bigbounty Last month i'm asking you how to get **review** data in this marketplace and it has been solved. But, because this scrape data will be my thesis analysis, i need to get more field from each product in this marketplace. Especially, i need to get the **transactions** data, (example: **product name, price, num_transaction, num_views**). I've learn about the previous code to get review data. But can you teach me how to call another module like transaction data? I really need your help, thank you :)

Comment: hi @bigbounty can you help me pleaaseee :(. i'm very need this data